# ¿Cómo funcionan los nuevos operadores de ''nullabilidad'' en C#8.0?

Tags: c#, c#-8.0

Hace poco, leyendo acerca de [c#-8.0](/questions/tagged/c%23-8.0), me topé con cosas como las siguientes

```
string? field = null!
```

Usando el operador `?` donde antes no podía usarse e igualando a `null!` ¿qué es esto?.

Al igual que asignaciones como

```
string x;
string? y;    
x = y!;
```

¿Qué son estos operadores, cómo funcionan?

Comment: asociación: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54724304/what-does-null-statement-mean

Answer (score 17, accepted):

La clave para entender qué significa `null!` es entender el operador **`!`**, todos estamos acostumbrados a usarlo como negación, pero desde [c#-8.0](/questions/tagged/c%23-8.0) puede ser usado para controlar Nulabilidad.

### ¿Qué es el operador `!` cuando es usado en un tipo?

El operador `!`, cuando es usado en un tipo, se llama [Null Forgiving Operator](https://docs.microsoft.com/es-es/dotnet/csharp/nullable-references), fué introducido en [c#-8.0](/questions/tagged/c%23-8.0)

## Explicación técnica

#### Uso típico

Asumiendo la siguiente clase..

```
class Person
{
  public string? MiddleName;
}
```

El uso sería:

```
void LogPerson(Person person)
{
    Console.WriteLine(person.MiddleName.Length);  // ADVERTENCIA: puede ser null.
    Console.WriteLine(person.MiddleName!.Length); // No hay advertencia.
}
```

Este operador básicamente apaga el comprobador de null del compilador

#### Funcionamiento interno

Este operador le dice al compilador que algo que *puede* no lo es, y es seguro accederlo. En esencia, es expresar despreocupación respecto a la posibilidad de que una instancia sea null.

Una variable puede encontrarse en dos estados (al hablar de "null safety")

- Nullable - **puede** ser null.
- Non-Nullable - **No puede** ser null

A partír de C#8.0 Todos los tipos de referencia son Non-Nullable por defecto.

La "nulabilidad" puede ser modificada por estos dos nuevos operadores de tipo:

- `!` = de `Nullable` a `Non-Nullable`.
- `?` = de `Non-Nullable` a `Nullable`

Estos operadores son básicamente la contraparte uno del otro, el compilador utiliza la información que se define con estos operadores para garantizar la ''null safety''

#### Uso del operador `?`

1. Nullable `string? x;`

   - `x` es un tipo de referencia, por ende, por defecto es Non-Nullable.
   - Aplicamos el operador `?` que lo convierte en Nullable.
   - `x=null` funciona normalmente.
2. Non-Nullable `string y;`

   - `y` es un tipo de referencia, por ende, por defecto es Non-Nullable.
   - `y=null` genera una advertencia, ya que está intentando asignar un valor `null` a algo que se supone que no debe ser `null`

#### Uso del operador `!`

```
string x;
string? y = null;
```

1. `x=y`

   - ¡Ilegal! - `Advertencia: "y" puede ser null`
   - El lado izquierdo de la asignación es non-nullable pero el de la derecha es nullable.
2. `x=y!`

   - ¡Legal!
   - El lado izquierdo y derecho de la asignación son non-nullable!
   - Funciona, ya que se aplica el `!` a `y` y eso lo convierte en non-nullable!

> **ADVERTENCIA**: El operador `!` solo apaga el chequeador del compilador a
>   nivel sistema de tipos.
>   - En tiempo de ejecución, el valor puede seguir siendo null.

---

Esta es una traducción de la [**respuesta**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54724304/what-does-null-statement-mean) de [**Patrick Hollweck**](https://stackoverflow.com/users/6754222/patrick-hollweck) en [SOen](https://stackoverflow.com)

<sup><sub>Por favor, cualquiera siéntase libre de realizar correcciones/modificaciones en la traducción.</sub></sup>